# Puppeteer wait for lists coming up

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, puppeteer, scrape

The site i am working on have a button.

when i click the button using puppeteer it makes 10 more lists on `ul` element.

At first time the site have already 10 lists on the `ul` element and whenever click the button 10 more lists added to the `ul`.

So here is the question

How do i wait for 10 more lists coming up on `ul` element after click the button using puppeteer ?

ex)

> first state

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

> i want catch this moment after click the button

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried below methods also but it's not working.

```
 await Promise.all([
        page.click('button#fetch-next-page'),
        page.waitFor('*'),
        // page.waitForSelector('div.loop-item', { hidden: true }),
      ])
```

Comment: What are you expecting `page.waitFor('*'),` to do? If the button is instant/synchronous, then you shouldn't need to wait, otherwise how about `page.waitForFunction(expectedLength => document.querySelectorAll("li").length === expectedLength, 10 /* or whatever */)`? A [mcve] of the site behavior in question would be helpful.

Comment: I forgot the `{}` as the 2nd param to `waitForFunction` -- glad you noticed that and got your code working!

Answer (score 1):

```
 await Promise.all([
        page.click('button#fetch-next-page'),
        page.waitForFunction(
          prevLength => {
            const curLength = document.querySelectorAll('div.loop-item').length
            console.log(curLength)
            return curLength !== prevLength
          },
          {},
          prevLength,
        ),
      ])
```

keep previous lists length and pass it to page.waitForFunction's parameter works as i expected

Thanks a lot @ggorlen